# How can I do polynomial interpolation in R

Tags: r, numerical-analysis

I am aware of a function called `poly.calc` from library `polynom`. It seems to return a string that can't be used to computing directly. Is there another similar function or is there other work around?

Comment: Hi Preston. What is it you wish to know?

Comment: Functions to generate polynomials in several standard ways

poly.calc (alias poly.from.values) computes the Lagrange interpolating polynomial. poly.from.zeros (alias poly.from.roots) computes the monic polynomial with specified zeros. poly.orth calculates polynomials orthogonal over a discrete set of x−values, as done numerically by the standard R function poly. Ref https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PolynomF/versions/1.0-2/topics/poly.calc

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.